# Designing Notification database table

Tags: mysql, database-design, notifications

I develop a notification table in MySQL whom attributes are
1.Created_At DateTime using current timestamp
2.notification_type varchar(100)
3.IS_Read boolean
4.message which I've to show according to the notification type
5.Notification_ID auto_Increment as a primary key
These are the attributes which I enter in my notification table

 
Now my questions is that Are these attributes are enough ?? or should I have to add more ??? What attributes should be in the notification table ??

**Edited**

Ok now my notification table attributes look like
1.Created_At DateTime using current timestamp
2.notification_type varchar(100)
3.Status int(2) in this I'll store notification status that it is shown and is read or not in binary format [ 00 , 01 , 10 ,11 ]=left side of binary reperesentation indicates whether the notification has been read and the right side is whether it's hidden.
4.message which I've to show according to the notification type
5.Notification_ID auto_Increment as a primary key
6.User_ID as a foreign key from table users. whenever some deletion insertion or updation is applied the notification generate and send it to the relevant user from this User_ID.
Now again my question is same
Are these attributes are enough ?? or should I have to add more ??? What attributes should be in the notification table ??

Comment: Where are you planning to show these notifications? In a website? In a mobile app? As a browser app?

Comment: The 2nd question is extremely broad because it is a design question.

Comment: I'm making this for a website and want to show notifications like facebook or stakeoverflow.

Comment: @Shadow  yes the second question is about design that how to show a notification to users when some insertion or deletion is done like in stakeExchange when a new notification comes it shows that you have 1 notification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is too generic, and it is very hard to answer it.
But I will still try to answer them, in a more conceptual manner:

1. You should always add a primary key to your tables, especially to this one, as you are going to update the row, in order to set the `is_read` field. In this case you need some kind of ID, you can call it `id`, this ID will represent a notification ID, and it should be an auto-increament.
   Also, I would anter a `status` field instead of `is_read` to indicate the several states possibilities for a single notification.
   Also, I think your table is missing a destination object, for example the user that this notification is related to. In case of general notifications (to all users), you do not ned this.
2. Basically, if you want to show it inside your website, you should create a script (PHP script in your case) that receives all unread notifications (or all of a specific user) from the DB and returns a list of notification messages, a long with their IDs, in a JSON or any other format you like. Then the client (JavaScript for example in your website) should call this script in order to get the list of notification to show. You can setup a script to check every several minutes to search for any new notifications (or use a socket connection, but it's more complicate as a POC, especially for someone who new to this).

I hope this explains the basic concept for how it should works, and where you should start.
If you have a more specific or technical questions, I would be happy to assist.

Good Luck!

---

> now could you explain more about status variable

Status is represented as `INT` and it's yours to decide. For example, if you want to hide your notification from the notification panel, then it should be indicated by status. Let's say you have two different state types, hidden or not, and read or not. In this case it is so classic to create the status in the following binary representation: 11, 10, 01, 00. When the left side of the binary representation indicates whether the notification has been read and the right side is whether it's hidden.
For example:

- Status 0, represents `00` in binary, means that the notification is shown, and not read.
- Status 1, represents `01` in binary, means that the notification is hidden, and not read.
- Status 2, represents `10` in binary, means that the notification is shown, and it has been read.
- Status 3, represents `11` in binary, means that the notification is hidden, and it has been read.

Later you can easily check with binary operators, for each case, for example in JavaScript:

```
var STATUS_READ = 2;
var STATUS_SHOW = 1;

function isRead(status)
{
    return !!(status & STATUS_READ);
}

function isVisible(status)
{
    return !!(status & STATUS_SHOW);
}
```

---

> also please elaborate the destination object which you are talking about, that how it works and when to use and why. Also tell me about the destination object datatype

Let's say you have users in your system. Each user have its own `user_id`.
Let's say you wnat to show a notification per user, therefor, you should also attach the notification destination user in your notifications tables.
In this case you should add the column `user_id` which holds the ID of the user, usually it is represented as `INT`, but it can also be a `username` wich is `VARCHAR`, it depends how did you designed your user table.

Comment: I have added a primary key named notification_ID with auto increment. now could you explain more about status variable and its datatype . also please elaborate the destination object which you are talking about, that how it works and when to use and why. Also tell me about the destination object datatype. First I'll make its table than I'll start working on notification panel like facebook or stackexchange.

Comment: Seriously?! a downvote?

Comment: sorry it was by mistake my system got crashed that is why can you please elaborate what I ask

Comment: I will update my comment

Comment: can we do this by boolean 0 or 1 ??? 1 for read or 0 for not read ok please elaborate it

Comment: ok when user open the notification panel than i should have to true Status show and when it clicks on it than i'll make status_Read true. ok so what should be the datatype of status????

Comment: and what about destination object ??

Comment: i'm trying to upvote but it changes to -1 automatically but I'll tick your solution when we solve this don't worry (:

Comment: ok so do I  have to add user_id as a foreign key from users table ?? as destination object ???

Comment: It depends on your DB design: If you're using relations methodology in your database, then yes. If not, then it is not mandatory.

Comment: Sorry, I can't actually connect your words into a valid sentence.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience,

Comment: kindly look at my updated post and tell me that are these attributes are enough for a notification table??

Comment: @NaveedCheema you can always add more, but eventually you'll have to start with something

Comment: Does there is a need to add a link varchar attribute???

Comment: It depends on your functionality